# SQL Inner Join with Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, inner-join

I have the tables shown below.

```
Table1
Field1 Field2
ID111    1,500
ID112    100
ID111    250
ID114    50
ID114    20

Table2
Field1 Field3
ID111  Chris
ID112  Mary
ID114  John
```

What I'd like to have is the result shown below.

```
ID111 Chris 1,750
ID112 Mary  100
ID114 John  70
```

I've already achieved this by using 2 sql executions. And thanks to the ones who helped last night on this site, I just got it to work using only 1 sql statement. However, I'm not able to link the first table to the second table for additional information.

By using

```
SELECT SUM(ctotal) AS TransactionTotal 
FROM   table1 
GROUP  BY field1
```

I was able to achieve

```
ID111 1,750
ID112 100
ID114 70
```

I'm currently using this sql statement and it pops out an error.

```
SELECT SUM(ctotal) AS TransactionTotal, 
       table2.field3 
FROM   table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 
               ON table1.field1 = table2.field1 
GROUP  BY table1.field1
```

It says can't "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Field3' as part of an aggregate function."

If anybody knows a fix for this, I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: Include Table2.Field3 in your `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: table2.Field3 must be present in either group by clause or enclosed in and aggregate function such as SUM(), MAX(), MIN(), AVG(),...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should suffice-

```
  SELECT t1.firld1, t2.field3,
         sum(t1.CTotal) as cTotal
    FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
GROUP BY t1.field1, t2.field3
```

Whatever columns you are selecting in your `SELECT` statement that are not an aggregate function (i.e., the columns that are not using `COUNT`, `SUM` or other aggregate functions) should also be mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause.

This is not particularly followed in MySQL (yielding unwanted results sometimes) but it is mandatory in Oracle. Yet, most of the RDBMS will yield similar result when you use the query as above.

Comment: HOLY MOTHER OF VENUS, exactly the explanation I was looking for! Kudos! Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using? I could give you related links for your reference if I know what you're working with.

Comment: I'm using Access now. I usually just use Access during development stage. But when it's deployed, I always use MSSQL server 2005, 2008, or 2012. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Blorgbear and Matt Welch said, you need to include all columns that are not in an aggregate function in the group by.

The reason for this is that you are trying to tell it to sum one value, but not what to put in the other columns.

Think about the data you have in the other two columns, how does it know to show 100,250, or any other value for Field2 if you don't specify an action on it such as Min (pull the minimum value)

Here is a list of aggregate functions:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to `group by` the column you included in the `select`:

```
Select SUM(CTotal) as TransactionTotal, Table2.Field3 
from Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field1 
GROUP BY Table1.Field3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried your solution but now it says "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Field1' as part of an aggregate function." :(

Answer (score 0):

Add Field3 to the GROUP BY clause like this:

```
Select SUM(CTotal) as TransactionTotal, Table2.Field3 from Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field1 GROUP BY Table2.Field3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select SUM(CTotal) as TransactionTotal, max(Table2.Field3) Field3  from Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field1 GROUP BY Table1.Field1
```

or

```
Select SUM(CTotal) as TransactionTotal, Table2.Field3  from Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field1 GROUP BY Table1.Field1, Table2.Field3
```

Comment: table2.Field3 must be present in either group by clause or enclosed in and aggregate function such as SUM(), MAX(), MIN(), AVG(),...

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding entries in your `group by` statement, you could also write it as a CTE  using the `with` statement. You define the result set of the sums first, and then use a second query referencing that to output the data.

```
with total as (
  select Field1, SUM(ctotal) as TransactionTotal 
    from Table1 
    group by Field1
)
select Table2.Field1, Table2.Field3, total.TransactionTotal
  from Table2
  inner join total on Table2.Field1 = total.Field1
;
```